# Encapsulation Aggregation / Composition

Tags: clone, encapsulation, aggregation, composition

The Wikipedia  article about encapsulation states:

"Encapsulation also protects the integrity of the component, by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state"

I started a discussion about encapsulation on a forum, in which I asked whether you should always clone objects inside setters and/or getters as to preserve the above rule of encapsulation. I figured that, if you want to make sure the objects inside a main object aren't tampered with outside the main object, you should always clone it.

One discussant argued that you should make a distinction between aggregation and composition in this matter. Basically what I think he ment is this:

- If you want to return an object that is part of a composition (for instance, a Point of a Rectangle), clone it.
- If you want to return an object that is part of aggregation (for instance, a User as part of a UserManager), just return it without breaking the reference.

That made sense to me too. But now I'm a bit confused. And would like to have your opinions on the matter.

Strictly speaking, does encapulation always mandate cloning?

PS.: I program in PHP, where resource management might be a little more relevant, since it's a scripted language.

Comment: You're confusing encapsulation with immutability. Cloning may only be _sometimes_ appropriate when you want to achieve the latter; it has nothing to do with the former.

Answer (score 3):

> Strictly speaking, does encapulation always mandate cloning?

No, it does not.

The person you mention is probably confusing the protection of the *state* of an object with the protection of the implementation details of an object.

Remember this: Encapsulation is a technique to increase the **flexibility** of our code. A well encapsulated class can **change its implementation without impacting its clients**. This is the essence of encapsulation.

Suppose the following class:

```
class PayRoll {
   private List<Employee> employees;

   public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
       this.employees.add(employee);
   }
   public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
       return this.employees;
   }
}
```

Now, this class has low encapsulation. You can say the method *getEmployees* breaks encapsulation because by returning the type List you can no longer change this detail of implementation without affecting the clients of the class. I could not change it for instance for a Map collection without potentially affecting client code.

**By cloning the state of your object, you are potentially changing the expected behavior from clients.** This is a harmful way to interpret encapsulation.

```
public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return this.employees.clone();
}
```

One could say the code above improves encapsulation in the sense that now addEmployee is the only place where the internal List can be modified from. So If I have a design decision to add the new Employee items at the head of the List instead of at the tail. I can do this modification:

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    this.employees.insert(employee);  //note "insert" is used instead of "add"
}
```

However, that is a small increment of the encapsulation for a big price. Your clients are getting the impression of having access to the employees when in fact they only have a copy. So If I wanted to update the telephone number of employee John Doe I could mistakenly access the Employee object expecting the changes to be reflected at the next call to to the PayRoll.getEmployees.

A implementation with higher encapsulation would do something like this:

```
class PayRoll {
   private List<Employee> employees;

   public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
       this.employees.add(employee);
   }
   public Employee getEmployee(int position) {
       return this.employees.get(position);
   }
   public int count() {
       return this.employees.size();
   }
}
```

Now, If I want to change the List for a Map I can do so freely.
Furthermore, I am not breaking the behavior the clients are probably expecting: When modifying the Employee object from the PayRoll, these modifications are not lost.

I do not want to extend myself too much, but let me know if this is clear or not. I'd be happy to go on to a more detailed example.

Answer (score 0):

No, encapsulation simply mandates the *ability* to control state by creating a single access point to that state.

For example if you had a field in a class that you wanted to encapsulate you could create a public method that would be the single access  point for getting the value that field contains.  Encapsulation is simply this process of creating a single access point around that field.

If you wish to change *how* that field's value is returned (cloning, etc.) you are free to do so since you know that you control the single avenue to that field.

Comment: I see what you are saying. That makes sense. Thank you.